# Define stages without files

Tags: capistrano3

Is it possible to define a Capistrano stage without using files?

I have a set of apps with similar deployment configuration and I would like wrap common Capistrano settings within a library, but currently the *file per stage* is forcing me to copy/paste many of my settings.

I believe it is possible to change the stage files folder location, but even so, I would like the flexibility to define them by code, like:

```
stage :production do
  server 'my.server.com', user: 'my_user', roles: %w{web app}
end
```